# What does Girsanov rule out?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $X$ be a semimartingale under probability measure $P$ with representation $X = X_0 + M + A$ where $M$ is a martingale and $A$ is a finite variation process.  Suppose $X = X_0 + N + B$ under $Q$, where $Q$ is another probability measure that is equivalent to $P$, $N$ is a $Q$-martingale, and $B$ is a finite variation process.  Girsanov's theorem tells us how to relate $M$ and $N$, and $A$ and $B$, respectively.

**Question:**  If we know that $A$ is actually absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, does Girsanov tell us that $B$ must be so too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no in general. You are assuming that $A\ll \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on the time axis. If the Lebesgue measure also dominates $\langle M,M\rangle$, so that 
$$\langle M,M\rangle\ll \lambda,\tag{1}\label{1}$$
then yes.

The following can be helpful. If there is an equivalent local martingale measure (ELMM) for $X$ then 
necessarily $A\ll \langle M,M\rangle$. If ELMM exists then necessarily 
$B \ll \langle M,M\rangle$. If additionally we know that \eqref{1} holds then you get what you wanted.

Comment: I see.  Is there a reference telling me that $A \ll \lambda$ and $\langle M, M \rangle \ll \lambda$ imply $B \ll \lambda$?  Also, is there a reference for the second part of the answer?  Your answer rules out the possibility that one can de-drift the process $L_0(t) + B_t$, where $B_t$ is standard BM and $L_0(t)$ is local time.

Comment: How does it follow from Girsanov that $\langle Z,M \rangle \ll \langle M,M \rangle$?  Otherwise, I see everything else.